# Using a graph-tool efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, graph, networkx, graph-tool

After a long thought, I finally decided to post this question here. Few days back I started using `graph-tool` to do various things. I have been using `Networkx` before that. I have already seen the impressive [performance comparision](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/performance) and thought that everything would be simple enough. However, I immediately ran into the speed issue and [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193773/graph-tool-surprisingly-slow-compared-to-networkx) related to a particular aspect of it. I got a quick answer that satisfied me. However, now this speed issue is bugging me every now and then and I can't find any documentation about `graph-tool` that is related to efficiently using it. For example, from the answer to my last question, I came to realize that it is better to add all edges together instead of one by one which is a very important point to note but hasn't been mentioned anywhere! I am now having two more similar issues:

(1) How do I choose a random neighbour of a given node? I can only see the following solution:

```
nbr = np.random.choice(list(v.all_neighbours()))
```

since `v.all_neighbours()` is a generator, I must convert it into the list to choose a random element. This slows down the code but I don't see any better way.

(2) I want to assign a 1d vector (is `list` okay?) to each of the vertices in the graph and later I am exchanging and modifying them in a particular way. This is simply a property map and I would like to see some documentation about how to use this efficiently. However, I can't locate anything.

(3) I am trying to simulate a [triadic closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triadic_closure) in some network which itself is changing with time. Thus, at every time step, I need an information about the neighbours of each vertex in the graph. Again, I must create a list (or numpy array):

```
nbrs = [w for w in v.neighbours()]
```

which decreases the speed of my code substantially. This means that I am not doing this correctly but I couldn't find any documentation that would tell me how to use neighbours efficiently in graph-tool.

Somehow `Networkx` programs that I have written for same tasks have completely outperformed the graph-tool codes I simply can't buy this.

This list might increase and hence I would be very glad if somebody could point me to some documentation about using graph-tool efficiently apart from answering the above mentioned specific questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Giving the accepted answer of the linked question a quick look, it seems you can add edges in one-go with [`add_edges_from`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.add_edges_from.html), if that's one bottleneck. Oops that might not be relevant, as I assumed that `networkx` there.

Comment: Right. Do you have any other idea about graph-tool? Networkx, contrary to my expectations, is working quite fast. This simply means that I am not using graph-tool correctly.

Comment: I don't really have any experience working with `graph-tool`, in fact hearing about it for the first time. But if they claim it to be efficient, I would hope they would have some implementation to match up that functionality of adding all edges in one-go, like in `networkx`. Nevertheless, I got try out that module myself, looks interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access neighbours and vertices as arrays, which will speedup your code, as described in the documentation: https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/quickstart.html#fast-iteration-over-vertices-and-edges

For example, instead of doing:

```
nbr = np.random.choice(list(v.out_neighbours()))
```

you should do:

```
nbr = np.random.choice(g.get_out_neighbours(v))
```

which should be substantially faster, as arrays are used instead of lists.

Comment: This throws an error: `AttributeError: 'Vertex' object has no attribute 'get_all_neighbours'`

Comment: @Peaceful you are probably using an old version. You need to upgrade.

Comment: I am using the version 2.26 which I upgraded to today. I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the answer. I fixed it now.

Comment: Still throws the same error. Is it because I am on Ubuntu 16.04 instead of the latest OS version?

Comment: Sorry, there was _still_ another typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to make more "`graph-tool`-specific" answers:

1) well actually this one is related to python, so you might want to use the solution from [this thread using `random.shuffle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581437/python-random-sample-with-a-generator)
However, if you are going to do this repeatedly, (and if you have enough available memory), I think it might be better to get the adjacency matrix as a `scipy` sparse matrix then use that matrix:

```
import graph_tool
from graph_tool.spectral import adjacency
import numpy as np

g = graph_tool.Graph()
g.add_vertex(100)
edges = np.random.randint(0, 100, (500,2))
g.add_edge_list(edges)

mat = adjacency(g).tolil()
rows = mat.rows.copy() # mat.rows = in-neighbours for each vertex
map(np.random.shuffle, rows)
rnd_neighbours = { i:row[0] for i, row in enumerate(rows) if row }
```

Where `rnd_neighbours` contains the index of one random neighbour for each vertex of nonzero in-degree.

2) reading the [`graph-tool` documentation regarding `PropertyMaps`](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/graph_tool.html#graph_tool.PropertyMap) and the [detailed version](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/quickstart.html#sec-property-maps), `list`s are accepted as `python::object` or simply `object`. You can then access them as elements in the `PropertyMap`.

3) For triadic closure, look at the [clustering module](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/clustering.html?highlight=clustering#module-graph_tool.clustering) and at [this thread](http://main-discussion-list-for-the-graph-tool-project.982480.n3.nabble.com/Triangle-Counting-td4026531.html#a4026534) on the mailing list.

EDIT: by the way, I forgot to mention it, but you can access and change the number of OpenMP threads with `openmp_enabled`, `openmp_get_num_threads`, and `openmp_set_num_threads` in `graph-tool`. Can't find it in the doc, though... But here is [the source](https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/blob/master/src/graph_tool/__init__.py#L3112).